# Fun time! Guess what I am!

Tags: riddle

I enjoy a symmetry
and my motion is oscillatory

From the tip of your hand
I spiral down to the end

I am graceful and sinuous
but to use me is not arduous

You probably used me
What could I be?

Comment: maybe using tag [tag:rhyme] ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you a

> Yo-Yo

Reasoning:

I enjoy a symmetry

> Yo-Yos are symmetrical

and my motion is oscillatory

> a yo-yo goes up an down (oscillating)

From the tip of you hand
I spiral down to the end

> yo-yos are tied to a finger and unroll down turning all the while

I am graceful and sinuous
but to use me is not arduous

> yo-yos go in a sinusoidal pattern if you view someone walking while using one and using one is something even a child can do. :)

You probably used me
What could I be?

> many people used a yo-yo when they were a kid.

Comment: I had the word "slinky" in mind but a yo-yo counts as well.

Comment: +1 Nice Answer, think you've got it

Answer (score 0):

My guess is:

> Helter Skelter

I enjoy a symmetry

> H**elter** Sk**elter**

and my motion is oscillatory

> Not sure - Pending

From the tip of you hand

> Not sure - Pending

I spiral down to the end

> The motion of the ride

I am graceful and sinuous

> Helter Skelter could be described that this

but to use me is not arduous

> Its not difficult to ride

You probably used me

> Most individuals have been in this ride as a children

Title -

> A Helter Skelter falls into the category of amusement rides which are associated with fun